# fmtutil fails to build certain formats

Tags: babel, format-files, fmtutil

I'm on a relatively fresh manjaro linux install (pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Arch Linux)) and because of reasons (see below) I want to rebuild my format files with `fmtutil`. I'm using this command to do it:

```
fmtutil --user --all
```

Which seems to run fine, but ultimately fails to build some of the formats:

```
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /home/totoro/.texlive/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdfcslatex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /home/totoro/.texlive/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdfcslatex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=dvilualatex -progname=dvilualatex dvilualatex.ini </dev/null' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=pdfjadetex -progname=pdfjadetex *pdfjadetex.ini </dev/null' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=jadetex -progname=jadetex *jadetex.ini </dev/null' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=eplain -progname=eplain -translate-file=cp227.tcx *eplain.ini </dev/null' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `xetex -ini   -jobname=xelatex -progname=xelatex -etex xelatex.ini </dev/null' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luahbtex -ini   -jobname=lualatex -progname=lualatex lualatex.ini </dev/null' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
fmtutil [INFO]: disabled formats: 5
fmtutil [INFO]: successfully rebuilt formats: 34
fmtutil [INFO]: failed to build: 6 (luatex/dvilualatex pdftex/pdfjadetex pdftex/jadetex pdftex/eplain xetex/xelatex luahbtex/lualatex)
fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 45
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 6
```

I'll give the final error messages here, you can find the complete log of the run [over here](https://pastebin.com/PE5c2VhC). Many (all?) of these fails seem to somehow be connected to `\UnicodeEncodingName`, which gets thrown up as an undefined control sequence.

I'm not sure how to fix this? Does anyone have an idea?

---

**XY-Problem-Disclaimer:**

The problem I'm ultimately trying to solve is the same one as [over here](https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/69), namely that I keep getting the following (manually skippable, but annoying) error in documents with `babel`.

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \bbl@foreign@x already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

The accepted solution there (and in [multiple](https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/72) [other places](https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/73)) is to `fmtutil --user --all`, which so far, hasn't resolved the issue for me, and I want to try to run it without error before opening a new bug report in the babel repo.

Comment: Local config file fonttext.cfg used
 
====================================
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/cslatex/base/fonttext.cfg

Comment: if you have write access it is strongly recommended to use fmtutil-sys rather than build user formats which almost always lead to version inconsistencies after updates your logs seem to suggest that you are picking up the cslatex fonttext.cfg file not sure why though.

Comment: instead of building local formats to resolve your babel problem you should better remove local formats, they shadow the system formats and so are often a source of errors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do have access, and `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` runs through fine (without the sudo, it produces identical output to earlier). The babel error still persists.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How can I remove the local formats?